# How do I use Fixtures.identify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fixtures

What are the parameters and what is the significance of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to the [usage](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Fixtures.html#M000150).

> Returns a consistent, platform-independent identifier for label. Identifiers are positive integers less than 2^32.

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb, line 531
  def self.identify(label)
  Zlib.crc32(label.to_s) % MAX_ID
end
```

Also, you might want to check out [Machinist](http://blog.markusproject.org/?p=1280), some people say it's easier but I've never used it.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't quite figure it out at first. How does it identify the fixture? I guess it checks the fixture and matches it up to the database?

Comment: Thanks for the help/patience! I think I've got it now.

Comment: great! let me know if you still have trouble.